# python tkinter popup window with selectable text

Tags: python, popup, tkinter

I want to make popup window using Tkinter.
I can do it so:

```
import Tkinter
a="some data that use should be able to copy-paste"
tkMessageBox.showwarning("done","message")
```

But there is one problem that user need to be able to select, copy and paste shown text. 
It's not possible to do in such way.

Are there any ways to do it with Tkinter?  (or another tools that is supplied with python by default)

Thanks in advance for any tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/316754/selectable-label-with-tkinter), it seems a workaround using `Entry` in Tkinter is doable. Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()

ent = Tk.Entry(root, state='readonly')
var = Tk.StringVar()
var.set('Some text')
ent.config(textvariable=var, relief='flat')
ent.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

*EDIT*: To respond to your comment, I [found](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_text_widget.php) a way to insert multi-line text, using the `Text` widget.
Here is a draft of a solution:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30, bg='lightgrey', relief='flat')
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
T.config(state=DISABLED) # forbid text edition
T.pack()
mainloop()
```

I'm (still) interested in any better solution :)

Comment: hm, it would be acceptable, but when I try to add a few lines like: line="text", line=line+"\n", line=line+"yet some text", var.set(line).   "\n" is interpreted like a symbol, but not a new line

Comment: interesting,text in this form cannot be copied (it can be selected as one wants, but copied) is it only me or can't you do it too?

Comment: ah, I've guessed, this is parameter in T.config  - state=DISABLED - controls whether text can be selected, so it should be set ENABLED, in order to allow for user selecting of text

Comment: Hum... sorry, the second example currently only support copy-paste with the scroll button under linux (had tested that by habit, not CTRL-c, CTRL-v, sorry again). There is a problem with NORMAL (ENABLED just does not exist): the text is editable. I'm currently attempting to solve this (tried to bind the `insert` method to a `do_nothing` function, without succeeding to cancel the editing capabilities)

Comment: It seems the binding with `<Control-KeyPress-c>` is disabled when `state=DISABLED` according to my experiments. [Listbox](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t329643-tkinter-cutnpaste-from-disabled-window.html) is also a possible solution but... it's further from what you asked.

Comment: The [tkinter documentation ][1] lists `state='readonly'`, which supposedly will display the text, make it selectable but not allow for modification


  [1]: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use buttons for copy and paste. First you need to select. In a text widget it is easily done by

```
selection=nameoftextwidget.get(SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
```

Then you can use this for copying easily by the use of selection. If you want to copy/paste it in that same text widget, you can use:

```
nameoftextwidget.insert(END,"\n"+selection)
```